# After upgrade to Xubuntu 20.04.1 white screen after login

Tags: xubuntu, login, xorg, xfce

**Problem**:

I updated my Xubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.1LTS, and stuck with issue. After i enter password for my user and press enter, i see white screen and cursor. If i press Alt+F4 (there should be a shutdown popup with buttons), and move cursor, i see how the cursor changes, so there is some windows under this white layer.

**What i tried**:

1. Reinstall `xubuntu-desktop` and `xfce`
2. Remove configs of xfce (~.config/dconf/user, ~.config/xfce4/panel, remove file xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml)
3. Comment lines to disable screen tearing (/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-amdgpu.conf)
4. Removed saved sessions of xfce.
5. Kill `Xorg`

**Hardware & Software**:

- AMD RX580
- Ryzen 5 3600
- Kernel: 5.4.0-48-generic

Also need to know:

1. i login successfully once, but i don't know how it was happened, and what was the reason. I tried to reboot because i think that problem was solved, but it wasn't. Next login there was also white screen.
2. I don't know how, but only once i saw a desktop with panels, but without windows (no close, minimize buttons). I opened terminal, typed `xfwm4 --replace`, the windows and screen become black and white.
3. On login screen if i choose Gnome session, everything works fine. The problem when i choose xubuntu session or xfce session.
4. Before update i was using arc-theme, maybe this is the reason? But i tried to switch to different theme via cli and it not help.

For any information, please, ask, i will provide what you asked for. I checked logs (Xorg, journalctl -xe), but i don't know what to look for.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solution was run `amdgpu-pro-uninstall` and return back to stock drivers (i event didn't know that i was using proprietary drivers)